# Passing command line arguments to a .ps1 file from Python's subprocess.Popen() method

Tags: python, powershell

I would like to pass command line arguments to to the file "my script.ps1", as well as pass `NoProfile` to the PowerShell executable.

The scripts (`c:/temp/my script.ps1`) content is:

```
param($param1, $param2, $param3)
$PSBoundParameters.Keys.count
$param1
$param2
$param3
```

I want to call this script within Python 3, I tried a number of quoting approaches and they are all failing. I can only call the script without arguments. The following is but some of the things I tried:

```
import subprocess
#subprocess.Popen(['pwsh','-file "C:\Temp\my script.ps1" "cat" "dog"'])        #Console Window Error -->  The argument '-file "C:\Temp\my script.ps1" "cat"' is not recognized as the name of a script file
#subprocess.Popen(['pwsh','"C:\Temp\my script.ps1" "cat" "dog"'])              #Console Window Error -->  The argument '"C:\Temp\my script.ps1" "cat"' is not recognize
#subprocess.Popen(['pwsh -file ','"C:\Temp\my script.ps1" "cat" "dog"'])       #Console window does not seem to open
subprocess.Popen(['pwsh','C:\Temp\my script.ps1'])                             #This is the only test that worked

input("Press enter to exit;")                                                  #Keep the console window open
```

I can run the `ps1` just fine on a PowerShell Terminal:

```
pwsh 'C:\Temp\my script.ps1' 'cat' 'dog'
2
Cat
Dog
```

Or:

```
pwsh -nologo -noprofile -file 'C:\Temp\my script.ps1' 'cat' 'dog'
2
Cat
Dog
```

I am working with PowerShell 7 and Python 3 on windows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the arguments to pass through to the script as separate array elements; ditto for `-NoProfile`.

```
subprocess.Popen(['pwsh', '-NoProfile', 'C:\Temp\my script.ps1', 'cat', 'dog'])
```

- The above is the equivalent of calling
  `pwsh -NoProfile "C:\Temp\my script.ps1" cat dog` e.g. from a PowerShell session.
- `-File` is *implied* with [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI (whereas [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, defaults to `-Command`). If you were to specify it, you'd have to place it in a separate array element just before the element specifying the script file path.

Comment: Fairly new to Python, I had no idea `subprocess.Popen()` has a variable parameter support. its working now. Thank you! Also its very usefull to know that `-file` is implied with core, perfect.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Ralf_Reddings; my pleasure.